# Fallo con el Gestor de sesion en manjaro

Tags: linux, archlinux, manjaro

hace poco tuve un problema cuando actualiza el sistema operativo linux (manjaro-xfce), este problema lo resolví luego de dos día de estar viendo en fotos y demás.

Luego de esto surgió un problema lo cual pasa cuando se suspende la maquina por inactividad se bloquea y me pide clave con el gestor de sesión por defecto de manjaro y justo después de poner las credenciales me arroja otro gestor de sesión que desconozco cual sea, pero este se encuentra gandido y no me deja hacer nada, y me toca reiniciar la maquina para poder seguir usándola.

Al parecer tengo dos gestores de sesión funcionando en conjunto y uno da conflicto con el otro , quisiera saber como ver cuales son estos y desactivar uno.

Comment: Usar `journalctl -xe` y ver qué error estás viendo puntualmente. Con detalles específicos es como puedes recibir respuestas.